# ExtJS 3 Checkbox Click Listener

Tags: extjs, checkbox, click, listener

Right now I have change listener but it requires the checkbox to lose focus to register. I looked around online and was unable to find out if such listener (or better substitute) exists.

Is there anyway at all to create a click listener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `check`?

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.Checkbox-event-check